# rpy2 and pandas: PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called

Tags: python, pandas, rpy2

I am trying to create a pandas DataFrame from an R Dataframe. I am encountering the following error, which I cannot figure out.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 291, in **init**
    raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

The code I am using is:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import r
robjects.r['load']("file.RData")
my_data = pd.DataFrame(r['ops.data'])
```

and the error comes after the last line.

Comment: What is `r['ops.data']`?

Comment: What about using the conversion utilities included in rpy2 ? There is one for pandas data frames.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read in data sequentially uses a for loop. DataFrames don't easily read in data in the way you are representing it. They are much more suited to dictionaries. Write some headers and then write the data underneath the headers.

Furthermore by saying ['ops.data'] means you are specifying "ops.data" as a data header. Obviously you can't read in an entire file as a column header